# Unable to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display the "loc" of a part if its part number I given.
Here is what the data structure looks like:

```
{
"parts":{
  "14521845": { "name":"TOOL EC160B/EC180B/EC210B/EC240", "loc":"EXC1", "sloc":"B3EGU01C03"},
  "12829050": { "name":"SWITCH; IGNITION SWITCH", "loc":"PS01", "sloc":"85-06-013"},
  "12829050": { "name":"SWITCH; IGNITION SWITCH", "loc":"COM1", "sloc":"B3RGK03D06"},
  "20044893": { "name":"PARTS CATALOG_ENG_SPA_FRE_GER_KOR_EC210D", "loc":"EXC1", "sloc":"B3EGT01B02"}
}
}
```

Activity Code:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference =firebaseDatabase.getReference("parts/"+curP);

            databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    Products data=dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);
                    Log.i("",String.valueOf(data.getLoc()));

                }
```

getLoc is the getter function for the Product class, and it returns the corresponding "loc" for the given curP. curP denoted the child values in parts.

The logic seems right to me, but I am not getting an output. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
getReference("parts").child(curP).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Products data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);
                Log.i("", String.valueOf(data.getLoc()));

            }
        });
```

Comment: Tried this, still no help                                                      DatabaseReference databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("parts/").child(curP);

                databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Products data=dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);
                        tv.setText(data.getLoc());
}

Comment: As per provided info. I think answer is valid. I think you have some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ValueEventListener. If you want read data once so use the addListenerForSingleValueEvent method, something like this:

```
private void getFirebaseLocValue(int curP) {
    FirebaseDatabase firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = firebase.getReference("parts");

    mDatabase.child(Integer.toString(curP))
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                Products data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);
                Log.e("TAG", data.getLoc());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Or you can use addValueEventListener and will get data with any changes. I really don't think that ChildEventListener is a good idea to retrieve data from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you are getting in `onChildAdded()` is not a whole Product object as you expect it to be.

In your database reference you are targeting a specific Product `("parts/"+curP)` but using a `ChildEventListener`. The children of a specific product node are `name`, `loc` and `sloc`, so the `onChildAdded()` will trigger several times, giving you each of these properties as a `dataSnapshot` separately.

The two patterns you might use to get whole Product objects are either:

- add a ChildEventListener directly to the "parts" node and you will get each of the Products as a child of that node, or;
- if you are adding a listener directly to the node of a particular product, use a ValueEventListener, to get the whole of that nodes entry as one `dataSnapshot`.

Comment: Tried using addValueEventListener to directly grab an object of Products class under the node of a particular product, still no output at all

Comment: Then it seems you probably have more than one problem, but the information in the question is only enough for us to spot this one. You would need to check other things, like your security rules, that the `Product.class` is correctly constructed, if dataSnapshot.toString() returns anything, if there are error messages in the console etc.